# Looping Stored Procedure too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, ms-access

Here I have a stored procedure that seems to be taking a little longer to run than I had hoped for. What made this algorithm so lengthy was the fact when adding an element to a new table in SQL it seemed to not always get put at the top.

I also had to query a query which created another table. All in all, this algorithm is too big. Does anyone have any ideas to make it shorter?

```
DECLARE @RecipeQuery TABLE(
RecipeID NCHAR(100),
MaterialID NCHAR(100),
Quantity DECIMAL(18,4));

INSERT INTO @RecipeQuery
(RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity)
SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity
FROM Recipe

DECLARE @PrevRecipeQuery TABLE(
prevRecipeID NCHAR(100),
prevMaterialID NCHAR(100),
prevQuantity DECIMAL(18,4));

DECLARE @TempRecipeQuery TABLE(
TempRecipeID NCHAR(100),
TempMaterialID NCHAR(100),
TempQuantity DECIMAL(18,4));

DECLARE @MaterialFinder TABLE(
RID NCHAR(100),
MID NCHAR(100),
Q DECIMAL(18,4));

DECLARE @PrevMaterialFinder TABLE(
PRID NCHAR(100),
PMID NCHAR(100),
PQ DECIMAL(18,4));

DECLARE @CalcMaterial TABLE(
CalcRecipeID NCHAR(100),
CalcMaterialID NCHAR(100),
CalcQuantity DECIMAL(18,4));

DECLARE @ROWCOUNT1 INT
SET @ROWCOUNT1 = 0

DECLARE @ROWCOUNT2 INT
SET @ROWCOUNT2 = 0

DECLARE @ROWCOUNT3 INT 
SET @ROWCOUNT3 = 0

DECLARE @isDone INT
SET @isDone = 0

DECLARE @mainRowCount INT

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--LOOP UNTIL ALL LEVELS HAVE BEEN FOUND
WHILE(@isDone != 1)
BEGIN

SET @mainRowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RecipeQuery)

--LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW IN THE TABLE UNTIL ALL ROWS HAVE BEEN LOOKED AT
WHILE(@ROWCOUNT1 < @mainRowCount)
BEGIN

--IF THE ROW'S MATERIAL STARTS WITH A "TempRecipeID" THAT MEANS IT IS DONE
IF(PATINDEX('R%', (SELECT TOP 1 MaterialID FROM @RecipeQuery)) = 1)
BEGIN
--INSERT THE ROW RIGHT INTO TABLE new
    INSERT INTO @CalcMaterial (CalcRecipeID, CalcMaterialID, CalcQuantity) SELECT TOP 1 RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity FROM @RecipeQuery
    SET @ROWCOUNT3 = @ROWCOUNT3 + 1
END
--OTHERWISE
ELSE
BEGIN
--FIND THE MATERIAL'S RECIPE AND PLACE THE NEW RECIPEID AND MATERIALID INTO TABLE TempMaterialID
    INSERT INTO @PrevMaterialFinder (PRID, PMID, PQ) SELECT TOP(1) RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity FROM @RecipeQuery
    INSERT INTO @MaterialFinder (RID, MID, Q) SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 RecipeID FROM @RecipeQuery), MaterialID, Quantity FROM Recipe WHERE RecipeID = (SELECT TOP 1 MaterialID FROM @RecipeQuery)

    DECLARE @ROWCOUNT4 INT
    SET @ROWCOUNT4 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @MaterialFinder)
    WHILE(@ROWCOUNT2 < @ROWCOUNT4)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @CalcMaterial
        (CalcRecipeID, CalcMaterialID, CalcQuantity)
        SELECT TOP 1 RID, MID, Q*(SELECT TOP 1 PQ FROM @PrevMaterialFinder)*0.001
        FROM @MaterialFinder

        DELETE TOP(1) FROM @MaterialFinder

        SET @ROWCOUNT2 = @ROWCOUNT2 + 1
    END
    SET @ROWCOUNT2 = 0
END

SET @ROWCOUNT2 = 0

--DELETE THE TOP ROW
DELETE TOP(1)
FROM @RecipeQuery

--INSERT THE UPDATED ROW(S) FROM TABLE TempMaterialID INTO TABLE W
INSERT INTO @TempRecipeQuery
(TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID, TempQuantity)
SELECT CalcRecipeID, CalcMaterialID, CalcQuantity
FROM @CalcMaterial

--DELETE THE UPDATED ROWS FROM TABLE TempMaterialID
DELETE FROM @MaterialFinder
DELETE FROM @PrevMaterialFinder
DELETE FROM @CalcMaterial

--INCREASE ROW COUNTER C
SET @ROWCOUNT1 = @ROWCOUNT1 + 1

--LOOP ONTO NEXT ROW
END
--AT THIS POINT ALL OF THE ROWS HAVE BEEN GONE THROUGH AT LEAST ONCE

--INSERT THE UPDATED ROWS IN TABLE W INTO THE MAIN TABLE 
INSERT INTO @RecipeQuery
(RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity)
SELECT TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID, TempQuantity
FROM @TempRecipeQuery

--TO COMPARE
--IF THE COUNT OF BOTH TABLES IS THE SAME THEY COULD BE THE SAME
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @prevRecipeQuery) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @RecipeQuery))
BEGIN
--IF THE DIFFERENCES BETWEEN THE TWO ARE NULL THEN THEY ARE THE SAME;
    IF(SELECT MaterialID FROM @RecipeQuery EXCEPT SELECT prevMaterialID FROM @prevRecipeQuery) IS NULL
--SET DONE TO 1 TO END LOOP
    SET @isDone = 1
END

--DELETE PREV TABLE FOR NEW UPDATE
DELETE FROM @prevRecipeQuery

--SET COPY INTO PREV
INSERT INTO @prevRecipeQuery
(prevRecipeID, prevMaterialID, prevQuantity)
SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity
FROM @RecipeQuery

--SET THE ROW COUNTER BACK TO 0
SET @ROWCOUNT1 = 0

--DELETE ALL FROM THE TEMP UPDATED TABLE SO THAT IT CAN BE FILLED WITH UPDATED ROWS IF AGAIN
DELETE FROM @TempRecipeQuery

--AT THIS POINT THE LOOP WILL REPEAT IF THERE ARE ANY MORE STOCK SOLUTIONS AS MATERIALS
END

--AT THIS POINT, ALL LOOPS ARE DONE AND THE MAIN TABLE DOES NOT CONSIST OF ANY STOCK MATERIALS AS MATERIALS
--PRINT THE MAIN TABLE
SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, Quantity FROM @RecipeQuery
ORDER BY RecipeID
```

**The input is the recipe table**
**The output is the Output needed table**, 
You can see the added rows are yellow as the query queries itself to find the material in each recipe.

Note that only columns and row 3 must appear in the final query. I added those to show how level 3 was generated.

[image: Test table]

INPUT:
Recipe  Material

aa01    B1
aa01    B2
aa01    bb01
bb01    B1
bb01    cc01
cc01    B3
cc01    B4
B1      B1
B2      B2
B3      B3
B4      B4

OUTPUT:
Recipe  Material

aa01    B1
aa01    B2
aa01    B1
aa01    B3
aa01    B4
bb01    B1
bb01    B3
bb01    B4
cc01    B3
cc01    B4
B1      B1
B2      B2
B3      B3
B4      B4

Comment: Looping should be avoided except for a few administrative tasks. You have multiple loops in here each of which are doing nothing but inserting data into table variables. Your entire procedure seems that it could be reduced to a single query. This current procedure by copying an entire table into a table variable. This whole thing needs to completely redesigned from the very beginning as a set based operation instead of row by agonizing row.

Comment: I tried to do that but it must continuously query the existing query to be able to do that and I could not figure that out without having premade the number of times it must query itself

Comment: To do this requires recursion. We have had recursive ctes available in sql server since 2005. There really isn't much anybody can do with this currently except post vague generalities. We have a definition of all your table variables but we don't have any sample data to start with or the desired output. I suspect this could run in a second or two with a set based approach but nobody can help without details.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have added a test table to help understand what needs to be done @SeanLange

Comment: Can you post a table instead of a picture. I really don't feel like recreating your table manually. But this looks like a very typical recursive cte. Maybe do a little digging on that topic and I bet you will find a solution that doesn't require all this looping.

Comment: Before I created this, I looked into Recursive CTE and I could not figure it out, I will look back into it but yes I can create a table.

Comment: I have put in text format the input of a table @SeanLange

Comment: So you want  a dynamic number of columns because the depth can go to any level?

Comment: Yes, it can be any number of levels. Although only the last level needs to be shown @SeanLange

Comment: What do you mean by last level?  And you said only row 3 but you have two rows highlighted. Why would you skip some levels of a recipe? I think there are some details that are not clear here or there are some issues with your table design.

Comment: You are not skipping any levels, rather you just need to see/read the last level. What is meant by last level the level where material is reached for every row. Because you have a recipe within a recipe within a recipe which is made up of materials. Therefore you just need the final output of all the materials in that recipe. The program is to breakdown continuously breakdown a recipe until it has all materials. Sorry about that

Comment: Why is B1 not in the output? It is a last level. Just like B2. They are both part of aa01 but have nothing deeper. Isn't that by definition the last level? And what is the entry point here? Are you starting with recipe aa01?

Comment: you have recipe aa01 made up of B1 B2 and bb01. Except you can see bb01 is made up of B1 and cc01. Therefore you get (b1 b2) (b1 cc01) except cc01 is still a recipe and contains materials. cc01's materials are b3 and b4 so you get (b3 b4).

Comment: The logic behind the output of aa01 is (B1 B2 (B1 (B3 B4)))

Comment: I give up. I put enough effort into this. I hope you figure it out.

Comment: I appreciate the effort @SeanLange

Answer (score 1):

**My story of how I improved performance of a while loop in SP:**

I was facing the same issue of slow performance of while loop looping almost half a million rows. I was looping using table variable and using an identity column as iterator. It was too slow. Later I changed table variable to a local temp table and created some indexes based on select commands inside the loop. The total time reduced drastically to just 2-3 mins from earlier time of 30 mins.
If you also have that many rows, try using temp table with proper indexes.

**In Short:** Try to replace table variables with temps tables with proper indexes.

Comment: You can have index on temporal tables too, http://www.sqlteam.com/article/optimizing-performance-indexes-on-temp-tables But yes index are your friends, use them.

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you mean, replace variables with temp tables ? how do you do such a thing?

Comment: He mean `CREATE TABLE` *(with index)* and `INSERT INTO TABLE` , instead of `DECLARE TABLE` But you can add index to temporal table too

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza can you please give me an example how I can use indexes?

Comment: I already link you the article. Or just goggle create index for msaccess

Comment: While a temp table may out perform a table variable if you really want to improve performance for this type of thing you need to stop looping and write set based logic. It will blow the doors off it.

Comment: @SeanLange I have tried other ways and this was my best answer

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza :My reason for using Temp table over a table variable was obviously number of rows. Microsoft also recommends using **temporary tables instead of table variables when number of rows is more than 100**. Microsoft docs link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql